# I want to add total of amount in frappe doc in print format

Tags: python, html, jinja2

```
Item Code
Item Name
Qty
Rate
Selling Price
```

{%- for row in doc.items -%}
{%
set rate=frappe.db.get_value("Item Price",{"item_code":row.item_code,"price_list":doc.price_list,"selling":1},"price_list_rate")
%}

```
{{row.item_code}}
{{row.item_name}}
{{row.qty}}
{{rate}}
{{'%0.3f'| format(rate\*row.qty|float)}}
```

{%- endfor -%}

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna add the total of the Selling Price column, u can create a variable total outside the for loop, and add the value of each row's Selling Price to it. At the end of the loop, you can display the total value.

```
{% set total = 0 %}
Item Code
Item Name
Qty
Rate
Selling Price

{%- for row in doc.items -%}
{% set rate=frappe.db.get_value("Item Price",{"item_code":row.item_code,"price_list":doc.price_list,"selling":1},"price_list_rate") %}

{{row.item_code}}
{{row.item_name}}
{{row.qty}}
{{rate}}
{{'%0.3f'| format(row.selling_price)}}
{% set total = total + row.selling_price %}

{%- endfor -%}

Total: {{ total }}
```